# SQL. Вывести количество стран по количеству букв в названии

Tags: sql, select

[image: Как сделать так чтобы не было повторений в поле Количество символов, при этом чтобы и Количество стран изменялось. Например есть 3 страны с количеством символов в названии 9, мой запрос выводит 3 строки, вместо того чтобы вывести - Количество стран: 3, Количество символов: 9.]
Как сделать так чтобы не было повторений в поле Количество символов, при этом чтобы и Количество стран изменялось.
Например есть 3 страны с количеством символов в названии 9, мой запрос выводит 3 строки, вместо того чтобы вывести - Количество стран: 3, Количество символов: 9.

Comment: Так а если сделать `GROUP BY [Количество символов]`? Ну или  `GROUP BY LEN(Название)`, если сразу так нельзя. Вам же именно эта группировка нужна.

Comment: Да, точно можно же использовать GROUP BY LEN(Название), спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

Не сразу понял вопрос вот так твой запрос сработает

SELECT
LEN(Название) AS КоличествоБукв,
COUNT(Название) AS КоличествоСтран
FROM
Страны
GROUP BY LEN(Название)
ORDER BY КоличествоБукв DESC[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы уникальные значения вывести можно использовать DISTINCT

Comment: DISTINCT тут не поможет, нужна группировка, как в другом ответе, а этот ответ следует удалить